# Prepared statements vs. escaping strings in PHP SQLite3

Tags: php, sqlite, prepared-statement

I'm working with SQLite3 in PHP.

A friend told me that I should prefer prepared statements, and I read this in many posts here on StackOverflow too. I want to understand the benefits of using prepared statements because I have to write much more lines, than regular escaping like using:

```
$db->exec("Insert INTO table VALUES(NULL,'".$db->escapeString($value)."')"
```

or using:

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $_POST[$k] = $db->escapeString($v);
}
```

Why should I use prepared statements? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14535337/472495, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8263371/472495, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5200238/472495

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People often confuse parameters with native prepared statements. I doubt Sqlite supports the latter, but nevertheless you have to **ALWAYS** use parameters to substitute the actual data in the query.

When parameter (also called "placeholder") being processed, important things happen:

- ALL the required formatting (i.e. escaping **and** quoting) applied (while escaping will do only **half** of the job - leaving your query wide open to injection).
- such a formatting being applied to the very data that is going to the query, not to the source variable, spoiling it (so, you can send it via email or store in a session).
- such a formatting being applied automatically, making your safety independent from the good will of developers. that's highly important matter

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it "insecurer", when i pass the variables in the "->execute" method instead of using "->bindValue"?

Comment: Nope, they are the same.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to print the final sql-string for debugging?

Comment: Should I expect significant difference in performance between single insert statement used with and without prepared statement?

Answer (score 1):

Prepared Statement is mostly used for avoiding `SQL injection` done by hackers and any malicious program.

Comment: herefor i can use ::escapeString, or???

Comment: There is no need to use `escapeString` because prepared statement is doing it by default.